# Access class methods from inclusion validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, class-method

I would like to include a class method as my options when using the inclusion validation:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  attribute :foo, Array
  validates :foo, inclusion: class_method_options

  def self.class_method_options
   ['foo', 'bar']
  end
end
```

However I get `undefined method 'class_method_options' for Search:Class (NoMethodError)`.

I tried Googling for the solution, but just found how to create a custom validation. I don't need a whole new validation, I just want to use the standard Rails inclusion validator. How can I access `class_method_options` from the inclusion validation?

Answer (score 11):

It's just not defined yet.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.class_method_options
   ['foo', 'bar']
  end

  attribute :foo, Array
  validates :foo, inclusion: class_method_options

end
```

That would work or you can do:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_method_options = ['foo', 'bar']

  attribute :foo, Array
  validates :foo, inclusion: class_method_options

end
```

Comment: Wouldn't the method name need to be a symbol?

Comment: @RichPeck, No in this case your just calling it at the class level.  As I said below, inclusion-in takes an enumerable, or a proc that returns and enumerable.  In this case there is no rails magic that calls a method for you based on a symbol.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do like this

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  attribute :foo, Array
  validates :foo, inclusion: {in: :class_method_options }

  def class_method_options
   ['foo', 'bar']
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work.  You have to pass an enumerable or a proc that returns an enumerable.  This may work if you change it to `{ in: &:class_method_options }`, but I haven't tested it.  More about inclusion validation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Answer (score 3):

Given `:in` accepts Proc, I ended up with

```
validates :foo, inclusion: { in: Proc.new { |search| search.class.class_method_options } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda too, like so:

```rb
validates :foo, inclusion: { in: -> { class_method_options } }
```

When doing it that way you don't need to have it defined before the call to `validates`.